# Javascript Template Literals and Html Textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea, template-literals, template-strings

To get some html to render nicely inside a textarea,

[image]

I have to make my code-indentation look ugly;
[image]

What's the proper way to write my template literal, without resorting to bad indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a separate script file instead, for which no indentation will be needed (or even appropriate) on the top level:

```
// script.js
const htmlStr =
`<section>
    ...
</section>`;
document.getElementById('txtHtmlStr').defaultValue = htmlStr;
```

```
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

I'd prefer to separate script files from HTML files anyway, they can [make things easier](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/250423) (eg, for proper separation of concerns, for having a single entry point, to permit linting, minifying, and transpiling)

Comment: Ok, that will work, but it is still resorting to moving everything to the left, which is weird; the editor position should not determine the outcome.

Comment: Having a separate script means that the natural position of the code *will already be* all the way to the left, by getting rid of the need for natural indentation. In a nested block, another option is to define the constant template literal on the top level, or to import it from a separate file.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I'll give it some time before coming back to accept your answer.